# Bad DLL Calling Convention in Excel

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I have tried the tricks posted here (at least the ones I have found), but I still can't seem to rid myself of the dreaded "Bad DLL Calling Convention" error. Here is my (very simple) c++ code:

```
VRTTCONVERSION_API long controlVTT(BYTE controlVal, BYTE valueVal)
{
    LPSTR controlStr = new char[256];
    PCHAR convstrout = new char[256];

    if (controlVal == 1) {
        controlStr = "Ping";
    }else if (controlVal == 2) {
        controlStr = "0 Init Tool Default";
    }
    if (bGetGeneralAccessFunctionPointer()) {
        return (pGeneral)(controlStr, convstrout, 256);
    }
    else {
        printf("failed to acquire function pointer.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This SHOULD accept bytes as inputs and return a long. I know the return works as I have another function that doesn't accept any inputs and returns the long and that one works fine.

Here is the VBA code (again, simple):

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function controlVTT Lib "VRTTConversionDLL.dll" Alias "#4" (ByVal controlVal As Byte, ByVal valueVal As Byte) As Long

Sub testControl()

Dim retval As Long
Dim bFunc As Byte
Dim bVal As Byte

bVal = 0
bFunc = 1

retval = controlVTT(bFunc, bVal)
MsgBox retval
bFunc = 2
retval = controlVTT(bFunc, bVal)
MsgBox retval    
End Sub
```

I know the #4 alias is correct (from using DLL Export Viewer). This function also works when I call it from another C++ function (see below):

```
int main()
{
    long retVal;
    retVal = controlVTT(1, 0);
    printf("Return: %08X \n", retVal);
    retVal = controlVTT(2, 0);
    printf("Return: %08X \n", retVal);
    return 0;   return 0;
}
```

Obviously, I'm not a professional programmer and I'm probably missing something basic, but I am truly stuck.

Comment: `LPSTR controlStr = new char[256];   PCHAR convstrout = new char[256];
    if (controlVal == 1) {  controlStr = "Ping";`  This is a memory leak of huge proportions.  Also, you can't learn C++ by winging it or by guessing what looks right.  Mistakes like the above are easy to make if you don't learn the language properly.

Comment: I'm just trying to get past the DLL calling error right now. I will get internal help from some people who understand C++ better than I do once I am able to just get the DLL working from inside Excel, which is the first hurdle I need to get over.

Comment: What is "VRTTCONVERSION_API"?  Does this mean `stdcall`, `cdecl`, etc?  That is what you should focus on to solve the issue.  Whatever it is, then the VBA function has to have the same calling convention.  That is basically it in a nutshell.

Comment: It is __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: So the calling convention, when not given in C++ is `cdecl`.  Is the VBA function using the `cdecl` calling convention?  If VBA cannot call `cdecl` functions, you need to change the C++ code to add `_stdcall`.

Comment: __cdecl VRTTCONVERSION_API long controlVTT(BYTE controlVal, BYTE valueVal) may help

Comment: @goldcode I believe it should be `__stdcall`, but not sure it comes before or after the `_declspec`.  In any event, the OP needs to change their C++ function to `__stdcall`, as I believe VBA uses this calling convention.

Comment: It may just be how the BYTE parameters are being marshaled - VBA chokes on unsigned types. I'd give `(controlVal As Any, valueVal As Any)` a shot before I tried anything else.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie right __stdcall is perhaps a better bet since its an 'inter-language' call.

Comment: Aha! VBA uses stdcall. I have changed my VRTTCONVERSION_API define and all seems to be working. Thank you very much!